# cannot resolve method setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds

Tags: android, textview, drawable

I am trying to set image resource with Strings

I have an issue with setting setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds, It keeps telling me

```
cannot resolve method setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, 0, 0, 0);
```

I have checked through online, even on stackoverflow, my implementation seems correct, but i can't compile.

```
String uri = "drawable/my_drawable_image";
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getActivity().getPackageName());
Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
myTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(image, 0 ,0 , 0);
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawable is an object. If you use the overloaded version of `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds`, that takes four `Drawable`, you can't pass `0` for not used/default value, but you have to pas null. Change

```
myTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(image, 0 ,0 , 0);
```

with

```
  myTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(image, null , null , null);
```

There is no version of `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` that takes a `Drawable` as first parameter and three `int`s. There is

`setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int, int, int, int);` as well. In this case your code will change like

```
myTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imageResource, 0 ,0 , 0);
```